# ios using itunes to upload an image to app

Tags: ios, file-upload, itunes

how can I have itunes uploading an image to the directory of my app on iOS

like user selects an png from her computer and upload that image to the file system sandbox of the app

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is called 'iTunes File Sharing'. With some googling you will be able to find plenty of tutorials about this, such as: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app